# VBA used range for specific columns minus the header

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an array using a loop and the used range function in vba. However, I only want the used range for specific columns and without the headers (1st row of each column). The code I have is below - I am not certain how to find everything except for the 1st row.

Thanks.

```
Col(1) = 9
Col(2) = 11
Col(3) = 13
Col(4) = 15
Col(5) = 17
Col(6) = 19
Col(7) = 21
Col(8) = 23
Col(9) = 25
Col(10) = 27
Col(11) = 29

Dim myArray() As Variant, myArray2() As Variant
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim x As Long

For i = 1 To 11

    Set DataRange = Worksheets(12).UsedRange.Columns(Col(i))

        For Each cell In DataRange.Cells
            ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
            myArray(x) = cell.Value
            x = x + 1
       Next cell

Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is don't use the Usedrange in initializing your DataRange to except the Header Row.

You can do something like this.

```
For i = 1 To 11
    lastRow = Worksheets(12).Cells(Rows.Count, col(i)).End(xlup).Row 'This is to find the last used row for the certain column. 

    Set DataRange = Worksheets(12).Range(Cells(2,Col(i)),Cells(lastRow,Col(i)))
Next i
```

Now you will have the specific range that you want.

Another thing that you can do to achieve your goal is to add an additional if statement for your range to check if the cell's row is the header.

```
For i = 1 To 11

Set DataRange = Worksheets(12).UsedRange.Columns(Col(i))

    For Each cell In DataRange.Cells
        If cell.Row > 1 then
            ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
            myArray(x) = cell.Value
            x = x + 1
        End if
   Next cell

 Next i
```

Comment: When I try to run the code with this addition I am getting a compile error for an "invalid qualifier" in regards to Cells(Rows.Count,Col(i)) in the calculation for lastRow. Any suggestions as to why this is occurring?

Comment: @AnneMarieMargaretMinniti the parens are off: `Set DataRange = Worksheet(12).Range(Cells(2,Col(i)),Cells(lastRow,Col(i))`

Comment: I edited my answer. 

Try to add an additional ")"  after the first cell. 

Set DataRange = Worksheet(12).Range(Cells(2,Col(i)),Cells(lastRow,Col(i)))

Comment: I have added the parentheses but am still getting the invalid qualifier error for lastRow.

Comment: Did you try to add a Dim lastRow as Integer on the initial part of your sub?

Comment: I did and unfortunately that did not help. The error is for "Rows" specifically in the code

Comment: You need to add "s" on you worksheet. 

 Set DataRange = Worksheets(12).Range(Cells(2,Col(i)),Cells(lastRow,Col(i)))

Comment: I added the additional if statement and that did what I needed! Thank you - I appreciate the help.